# Checking pthread cancelability state

Tags: c, pthreads

In saw that I can use pthread_setcancelstate to set the cancelability of a given pthread. (Enabling or Disabling it).
But, I can't find the matching "pthread_getcancelstate" function to check the cancelability state of a given pthread. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need that function?

Comment: It does not do what you think it does, it merely prescribes how pthread_cancel() is going to behave.

Comment: I want to check whether I can invoke pthread_cancel on a specific pthread. According to the man page, the pthread cancelability has to be enabled. I wanted to check that attribute, beforehand.

Comment: You are asking for a threading race bug.  You check => thread changes state => pthread_cancel() doesn't do what you hope.  Avoid talking about a solution you can't get, edit your question to focus on what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Why would one want to change the cancelability state after creating the thread? As far as I understand it's sort of an attribute you define upon creation. Similar to defining a thread as joinable or detachable. Take for example pthread_attr_getdetachstate. Why would this function exist but a "pthread_getcancelstate" won't?

Answer (score 0):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcanceltype.3.html

according to the man page setting a state will also get the oldstate it was configured in..
in that respect a simple get operation can be to set a state and then set the state back to the oldstate - i doubt that would effect your logic

the state you set back on the second call is the state the thread is in:

```
int curr_state;
pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, &curr_state);
pthread_setcancelstate(curr_state, NULL);
//curr_state is the result of your required get
```